# Correlating two measurements of a population with different number of unpaired observations

Tags: regression, inference

I have eight types of materials Mat1 to Mat8 (produced with different production parameters). From these eight populations I have measurements of a material property X which is easy to measure and measurements of Y which is harder and costlier to measure but is the property that we're interested in.

The idea is that X is related to Y and that by measuring we can estimate Y and avoid (at least partly) doing the direct measurement of Y.

The problem is that the measurements $x_i$, $y_i$ are not paired, and as a matter of fact there are much more sample values of X available than of Y. This situation I tried to illustrate with the following histograms.

[image]

If the measurements were paired I could try a regression Y=f(X) but it's not the case. I can try to compare the eight population averages $\bar x$ with $\bar y$, but then I lose the information about the sample variance of each population and can't compute confidence intervals.

Is there some statistical tool which I can use in this case to correlate these two measurements of a population with different number of unpaired observations??

Comment: If observations are not paired, what would correlation mean?

Comment: I mean a relationship between the random variables X and Y

Comment: Without pairing it seems hopeless, but maybe there is something you did not tell us?